# How after obtaining the instance of the vehicle and userApp class, how to pass the obtained values ​of longitude and latitude to the method?

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate

I have a problem because I don't know how I can how  pass the obtained values ​​of longitude and latitude to the method from my  my query to method which calculate distance between two points ?
I have a query which download a values user by id and return latitude and longitude user by id

```
 @Override
    public UserApp getUserByIdLocation(int idUser) {
        Session  session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        UserApp userApp =
                (UserApp) session.createQuery("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM pl.edu.wszib.model.UserApp WHERE idUser = " + idUser ).uniqueResult();
        session.close();
        System.out.println(userApp);
        return userApp;

    }
```

and I have query which download latitude and longitude Vehicle by id

```
@Override
    public Vehicle getVehicleLocation(int idVehicle){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Vehicle vehicle =
                (Vehicle) session.createQuery("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM pl.edu.wszib.model.Vehicle WHERE idVehicle = " + idVehicle).uniqueResult();
        session.close();
        System.out.println(vehicle);
        return vehicle;
    }
```

and I have method which calculate distance between two points

```
@Override
    public double  distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){
        double R = 6371e3; // metry
        double φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180; // φ, λ w radianach
        double φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI / 180;
        double Δφ = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
        double Δλ = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180;

        double a = Math.sin (Δφ / 2) * Math.sin (Δφ / 2) +
                Math.cos (φ1) * Math.cos (φ2) *
                        Math.sin (Δλ / 2) * Math.sin (Δλ / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2 (Math.sqrt (a), Math.sqrt (1-a));

        double d = R * c; // w metrach
       d = Math.round(d);
        return  d/1000;
    }
```

my userApp class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo",name = "UserApp")
public class UserApp implements UserDetails  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUser;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String role;
    private String locationName;
```

my vehicle class

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo",name = "Vehicle")
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idVehicle;

    private int idGroupVehicle;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private int maxRange;
    private int weight;
    private double pricePerSale;
    private int maxSpeed;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String locationName;
```

and my distance class

```
public class Distance {
    private double lat1;
    private double lon1;
    private double lat2;
    private double lon2;
```

how I can now put from this query download value and calculate distance based on the values ​​I downloaded
can someone explain?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you're asking. Are you asking, once you get an instance of `Vehicle` and an instance of `UserApp`, how to pass their latitude and longitude values to the `distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)` method?

Comment: yes exactly this is my question

Comment: You should improve your question, as it is it's really hard to understand. Furthermore you need to show how `Vehicle` and `UserApp` classes look like, and provide some more details regarding the class that contains the `distance(...)` method.